# Output value based on number range entered in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I need to find a formula that I can use for any number, and have it output a number identified to correspond to that range.

For instance, I need to be able to input:

A number >2.50 and  <7.49, and the formula spit out $0.05

A number >7.50 and  <24.49, and the formula spit out $0.10

A number >25.00 and  <74.99 and the formula spit out $0.50, and so on/so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a set of pre-defined values that you output as you showed in your example then I would use `=VLOOKUP()` like this:

[image]

Using this you can set what your desired output is in the table.  Now I cannot tell if there is a pre-defined pattern you are using to determine your outputs, if so a simple math algorithm might make more sense than this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this in a single formula:

```
=INDEX({0,0.05,0.1,0.5,10},MATCH(B1,{0,2.5,7.5,25,75},1))
```

You'll have to jiggle about with the cut-off points as you haven't stated clearly where the *between* values should fall, and what happens with larger or smaller values.